# Cuerpo del mail vacio

Tags: php

Me llegan los correos con el cuerpo vacio, en primer lugar pense que podia ser el name en el html pero no funciono esa solucion y ya no se que puedo modificar.

```
<form action="TestMail.php" method="post" name="contact-form" id="main-contact-form">
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" required placeholder="Nombre" class="form-control" name="nombre" id="name" >
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="email" required placeholder="Email" class="form-control" name="email" id="email" >
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" required placeholder="Asunto" class="form-control" name="asunto" id="subject">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <textarea required placeholder="Mensaje" rows="8" class="form-control" name="mensaje" id="message"></textarea>
            </div>
            <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Enviar</button>
                            </form>


<?php

        $mail_to = "info@gmail.com";
        $asunto="Contacto desde nuestra web";

        $name =  $_REQUEST["nombre"];
        $email = $_REQUEST["email"];
        $subject = $_REQUEST["asunto"];          
        $message = $_REQUEST["mensaje"];

        $content = "Nombres: $name\n";
        $content .= "E-mail: $email\n\n";
        $content .= "Mensaje:\n$message\n";

        $headers = "From: $name <$email>";

        $success = mail($mail_to, $asunto, $content, $headers);
        if ($success) {

            echo "¡Gracias! Tu mensaje ha sido enviado.";
        } else {

            echo "Oops! Algo salió mal, no pudimos enviar tu mensaje.";
        }

?>
```

lo que recibo es:

```
Nombres: 
E-mail: 

Mensaje:
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El envío de correo con `mail` es bastante artesanal.
Cada header tiene que terminar con `"\r\n"`.

```
$headers = "From: $name <$email>\r\n";
```

*Comentarios adicionales:*

Tal vez también te haga falta este otro header (para las respuestas):

```
"Reply-To: $name <$email>\r\n"
```

Y si lo pones en un hosting, probablemente también (para evitar ser mal visto como posible spam) -aparte de setear DKIM y SPF en el hosting-:

```
"Return-Path: $email\r\n"
```

Los parametros recibidos en el request tiene que ser validados para evitar posible manipulación por parte del usuario que hace el request.

Una sugerencia: Si querés simplificarte la vida con el envío de correo, fijate PHPMailer.

**Nota importante:** `$email` en los ejemplos es el email del que envía el correo desde el hosting (osea el tuyo del hosting), no el del usuario que está haciendo el submit. Lo comento porque en tu ejemplo está un poco confuso eso.

Answer (score 0):

Si te fijas en el método de tu formulario pone `POST` pero despue´s intentas cogerlos con un request. Por lo que yo creo que no estas cogiendo los datos del formulario.

Prueba a cambiar esto y si quieres haz la prueba de hacer unos `echo`para ver si estas reciviendo los datos.

```
$name =  $_POST["nombre"];
$email = $_POST["email"];
$subject = $_POST["asunto"];          
$message = $_POST["mensaje"];
```

Comment: Hice la modificacion que me indicastes pero sigue enviando el cuepo del mail sin los datos del formulario

Comment: Entonces será cosa de lo que te explica Juan en su respuesta. la cabecera necesita terminar con un "\r\n" porque sino se pierde.